# Why does API call in WordPress return HTML code?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a WordPress plugin that is used on a WooCommerce store. Now, in a specific part of my plugin, I want to create a function that makes an API call inside it using jQuery's AJAX. This function should be triggered when a user clicks a button. However, I'm encountering an issue where I'm getting an HTML response from the API instead of the expected data.

Where exactly is the problem?

I'm providing the code snippets below:

```
<?php
function get_api_token()
{
    $api_url = "http://37.156.28.62:8091/token";
    $username = "jbplugin";
    $password = "******";

    $response = wp_remote_post($api_url, [
        "headers" => [
            "Content-Type" => "application/json",
        ],
        "body" => json_encode([
            "username" => $username,
            "password" => $password,
        ]),
    ]);

    if (!is_wp_error($response) && $response["response"]["code"] == 200) {
        $data = json_decode($response["body"], true);
        if (isset($data["token"])) {
            return $data["token"];
        }
    }

    return false;
}
?>
```

```
    <script>
jQuery("#submitOrder").click(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "your_php_script.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text", 
        success: function(response) {
            try {
                var token = response;

                console.log("Token: " + token);
            } catch (e) {
                console.error("خطا در پردازش پاسخ: " + e.message);
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.error("خطا: " + error.statusText);
        }
    });
});
    </script>
```

Could you please help me diagnose the issue and find a solution while adhering to Stack Overflow's guidelines?

Translated the text as per your request! Please let me know if you need further assistance.

.........................................................................

Comment: what is the response that you are getting? Does the HTTP request look correct in the console?

Comment: My request is of type HTTP, and in the PHP function section, the output is a bearer token. However, when I click on the button, I want this function to be executed.

Comment: First of all, when you can make direct call from AJAX request then why you're using PHP script to do that? second why are you passing the dataType: text in the AJAX request?

Comment: When you make a jQuery AJAX request with dataType set to 'text', the response from the server will be returned as a plain text string.

Comment: I must say that in this API, I ultimately receive a bearer token. If I set it to "text," it returns HTML, and if I set it to "json," it still returns HTML but with the error message: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON."

Answer (score 0):

Here are the issues I have find in above code.

1. Your provided API URL `"http://37.156.28.62:8091/token"` is insecure as it uses HTTP instead of HTTPS. This could lead to security vulnerabilities. Consider switching to an HTTPS endpoint.

---

2. The URL you've provided in the jQuery AJAX call is `"your_php_script.php"`. If this is a placeholder, make sure you replace it with the actual URL.
   However, this is not the WordPress way. Instead, you should be using the AJAX API in WordPress. Here's a more WordPress-centric approach:

   a. Register a custom AJAX handler in WordPress.
   b. In this handler, call your function `get_api_token().` 
   c. Return the result as JSON to the AJAX request.

---

3. You've set dataType: `"text"` in your AJAX request. If you're expecting JSON, you should use dataType: `"json"`.

Here is the some code, Hope this will help.

**WordPress AJAX Handler, you can use this in function.php or in your plugin.**

```
function ajax_get_api_token() {
    $token = get_api_token();
    if ($token) {
        wp_send_json_success($token);
    } else {
        wp_send_json_error('Failed to retrieve token');
    }
}
add_action('wp_ajax_get_api_token', 'ajax_get_api_token'); // If user is logged in
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_api_token', 'ajax_get_api_token'); // If user is not logged in
```

**2. Adjust jQuery AJAX Call**

```
jQuery("#submitOrder").click(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            action: "get_api_token"
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.success) {
                console.log("Token: " + response.data);
            } else {
                console.error("Error retrieving token: " + response.data);
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.error("خطا: " + error.statusText);
        }
    });
});
```

Make sure you enqueue your script properly in WordPress so that jQuery is available when your script runs. I am sure this will help.

Comment: In the console, the error message returned without any additional explanation!

Now, I have a question: In which file should the API function be implemented and used exactly?